# How to optimize mysql query with multiple fulltext matches

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT heading FROM table_a, table_b as m1, table_b as m2 WHERE (m1.join_id = '69' AND MATCH(m1.content) AGAINST('Harry' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (m2.join_id = '71' AND MATCH(m2.content) AGAINST('+Highway +Design' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND m1.webid = table_a.id AND m2.webid = table_a.id
```

Right now it takes about 3 seconds. If i take out one of the conditions like this:

```
    SELECT heading FROM table_a, table_b as m2 WHERE (m2.join_id = '71' AND MATCH(m2.content) AGAINST('+Highway +Design' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND m2.webid = table_a.id
```

It takes around 0.05 seconds.

I have a fulltext index on the 'content' column.

Also, in the first query, if I were to search for 'Highway Design' (no operators like + or "") it takes about 30 seconds.

Here is my explain query:

```
    d   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
    1   SIMPLE  m1  fulltext    id_index,content_ft     content_ft 0        1   Using where
    1   SIMPLE  table_a     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   user.m1.id  1    
    1   SIMPLE  m2  fulltext    id_index,content_ft     content_ft  0       1   Using where
```

Is there anything else I can do to speed it up?

To explain my tables,
table_a is the main table that has a heading, and a content field and
table_b is my attribute table for the rows in table_a, so that rows in table_a can have additional attributes.

Let me know if I need to explain this better.

Thanks!

UPDATE here is the explanation of the fast query:

```
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
    1   SIMPLE  m2  fulltext    id_index,content_ft     content_ft  0       1   Using where
    1   SIMPLE  table_a     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   user.m2.webid   1
```

ANOTHER UPDATE - TABLE definitions:
Table_b

```
    id  int(11)             No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
join_id     int(11)             No  None
webid   int(11)             No  None
content     text    utf8_general_ci         No  None
```

Indexes for content table_b

```
    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  2723702 A       
    content BTREE   No  No  content (333)   226975  A       
    id_index    BTREE   No  No  webid   151316  A       
    content_ft  FULLTEXT    No  No  content 118421
```

Table_a

```
    id  int(11)             No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
    heading     text    utf8_general_ci         Yes     NULL
```

Table a indexes

```
    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  179154  A       
    heading BTREE   No  No  heading (300)   89577   A   YES
```

Comment: Show an EXPLAIN of the second fast query

Comment: Just did, let me know if you need any other info. Thanks!

Comment: I think table definitions would be useful too.

Comment: okay, let me grab those real quick

Comment: Sorry about that, trying to do too many things at once, where i had table_a_id, should have been webid, i just fixed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my first opinion would be to change one of fulltext searches to `LIKE` clause. For this purpose it would be good to have an index on **webid**, or even better a **composite** index on (webid, join_id). This should help for more consistent table joining.

Comment: Okay great, I will give this a try, I guess the question is which should be like and which should be fulltext?

Comment: @Gerry It's better to test because I don't know much about your data.

Comment: FYI- it's going to be a couple hours before I can test this, I will mark your answer correct as soon as I can :)

Comment: @Gerry My answer doesn't mean it is necessarily correct. Firstly make a test then we will see :) How fast the query was without a composite index using `LIKE`?

Comment: Ah, don't sell yourself short. I just got swamped with some other stuff, I am not be able to get to this until tomorrow, but I will post back here when I test it out.

Comment: I indexed join_id and now it's much faster! Thanks